# Ansible RBAC module

Tags: ansible, openstack, role-based-access-control

I would need to translate the following Openstack command in an Ansible task:

```
neutron rbac-create --target-tenant <TENANT_ID> --action access_as_shared --type network <SUBNET_ID>
```

Is any module that helps creating the RBAC in Ansible?

Answer (score 0):

For the beginning you could start just with the [`shell`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/shell_module.html)_module.

```yaml
- name: 
  shell:
    cmd: neutron rbac-create --target-tenant {{ TENANT_ID }} --action access_as_shared --type network {{ SUBNET_ID }}
  ...
```

Than proceed further with Ansible Collections and [Openstack.Cloud](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/openstack/cloud/index.html) modules and check which of the network related modules could fit for the [OpenStack Networking service (neutron)](https://docs.openstack.org/security-guide/networking.html) like [`openstack.cloud.network`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/openstack/cloud/network_module.html#ansible-collections-openstack-cloud-network-module).